# save /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr to files, and do log rotation?

Tags: linux

I am using docker with aws beanstalk and noticed that docker logs are printing out data output from console.log and console.err from our nodejs application.

My goal is to separate the stdout and stderr to 2 files, and let aws cloudwatch agent to pick up the file content and push to cloudwatch.
(by default, docker logs are pushed to cloudwatch automatically)

To achieve that, I have to:
1. save stdout, and stderr to 2 files
2. make sure the log can rotate otherwise it will become huge
3. setup beanstalk to picks the logs to cloudwatch

I am wondering if I can have some guidance to do 1. and 2.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: For 1 : https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file

Comment: For 2 : Do you know [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) ?

Comment: Thank you Jona, yes, I have heard of logrotate but have not tried to configure it. Thank you for pointing it out.